# Rails releationship between form and DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a text field in my rails form. How would I be able to allow users to enter a set or comma separated values, for example "12343, 121223, 32212", and store these strings in the database on new rows so that I can easily perform distinct counts on this field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can split the field value:

```
values = param[:field_name].split(', ')
values.each do |v|
  Model.create(:column_name => value)
end
```

I'm not sure if I understood right, your question is not really precise